# configuring database connection in Yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In the main.php file of the Yii framework, there are some configuration options. This is how it sets up mysql

```
'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

On my MAMP system, I have to specify the port as 8889. How would I add it into this?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I added the port like this and it seems to work

```
'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=testdrive',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

Answer (score 4):

can you not add it here to your connectionString

`'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive;port=8889',`