# can not PDO nuodb

Tags: database, yii, pdo, connect, nuodb

I want to connect nuonb with yii framework. After i configed from this guide ([configuring database connection in Yii framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121908/configuring-database-connection-in-yii-framework))
I cannot connect to database.
So I look at another page that config nuodb with php Framework.

http://www.nuodb.com/techblog/2013/06/20/using-nuodb-from-the-php-zend-framework/

I configed and test in command line I think it work case after i use this command

```
php -i | grep PDO

The Result is
----------------------------------------
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
```

But when I use function to test PDO in php with function phpInfo(), It can't find nuodb PDO ( PDO is no value).

Please help me fix this problem. 
Remark. My server is Aws Ec2 Ubunto.

Comment: You need to configure and install NuoDB first. Now you have LAMP server. http://dev.nuodb.com/techblog/nuodb-how-turn-lamp-powerful-scale-out-software-bundle is for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't trust this "nuodb" at all. Looks like a bubble.
2. You didn't install nuodb anyway, but mysql.
3. So - just go on with mysql!

Comment: Man we need to do something with databases, but yes, nuodb is not a best choice atm. Still in some time it will be interesting.

Comment: It never will be. A technology which uses only buzzwords on it's front page and nowhere explains it's details IS a bubble.

Comment: Yeap you right. Only water in documentation also. In 1-2 years if it wont die - maybe will be reason to look at it, untill its not usable in production mode, only for fun.

Answer (score 0):

@Sarun Prasomsri

What version of NuoDB are you running?

What version of PHP? (supported versions are PHP 5.4 TS VC9 and PHP 5.3 TS VC9)

@ Your Common Sense

NuoDB does install - it can run on a localmachine, datacenter, or AWS/Azure/Google Compute, like any other Database.

There are concrete details in the online doc: http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/NuoDB+Online+Documentation

techblog: http://dev.nuodb.com/techblog